# Restrict method argument to Objects that have a particular annotation

Tags: java, methods, parameters, annotations

I want to create a method that takes an argument. The argument must be an Object from any Class that has a specific Annotation. Calling this method by passing it an object that does not contain the specific Annotation must result in a compilation error.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What do u mean by "I want an error showed up when compile time"?

Comment: When somebody use that method and not pass a object that have specific annotation, compiler show an error. Sorry for my bad punctuation.

Comment: @WisnuWardoyo Welcome to stackoverflow.com. This seems to be your first question so I have edited it on your behalf. To improve the chances of getting an answer, you should avoid messaging slang in your question. Words such as `wanna` should be replaced with `want`. Also, providing some code snippets may also help us give you a better answer. Last but not the least, questions should be to the point and greetings should ideally be avoided. (Not a mandate but getting to the point straight away is always a good thing). I have edited your question and removed irrelevant text from it.

Comment: @bot Thank you sir. I'll try to be better when asking next question.

Comment: @WisnuWardoyo that's not possible, and would be an abuse of annotations, IMO. Make this method take an interface as argument, and make all the objects implement that interface.

Comment: @JBNizet yes sir, maybe that was the only way. But sir, when the object implement an interface, how to make that object must implement an Annotation?

Comment: What I meant by "that's not possible" is: "that's not possible".

Comment: @JBNizet: I'd say, this is possible, using some fancy annotation processor, but it will be gargantuan overkill in the OP's case, where a simple interface is enough to accomplish the task.